# rhel + efsck + Deleted inode xxxxx has zero dtime

Tags: rhel, lvm, inode, resize2fs, e2fsck

when I try to resize the disk we get that

```
resize2fs /dev/sdb
resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Please run 'e2fsck -f /dev/sdb' first.
```

so when I try to do `e2fsck`

I get the following

```
e2fsck -f /dev/sdb
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Deleted inode 142682 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>?
```

is it ok ? to continue by entering `yes` option , or this is something that can delete the data on disk ?

Comment: Running `e2fsck -p device` has never caused any troubles for me. `-p` means to fix errors automatically. Errors like yours are among those which get fixed without user intervention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s OK to let `fsck` fix this, it refers to a deleted inode — the data has already been deleted, nothing more will be deleted.

Comment: Why is `dtime` even necessary? Can the inode bitmap not convey that the inode is not in use?